# Problem with removing image from cell and displaying new cell height

Tags: image, tableview, swift4

I made tableview with dynamic cell height depending on an label and image. I have two questions:
1. How to set programmatically size for label and image like you can see in comments inside class "Cell"? I tried with CGRect but as i can see i need to set height value which i don't know to do it since my label should have dynamic height.
2. I would like to remove image form cell if she have nil value and then make cell height depending on label only.

In this code i made size of label and image using storyboard. I think i would be able to solve this problem using an if statement where i set bottom space for label if image is nil.

Here is my code:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var picImage : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descLabel : UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        descLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        //set label size programmaticly, like (leading space to 40, top 20, trailling space to 40)
        //set image size programmaticly, like (Horizontally center, top 10 under descLabel, width 50, height 90)
    }


}
```

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    var arrOfPictures : [String?] = ["str", "", "str"]
    var arrOfDesText : [String] = ["sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text", "sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text", "sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.estimatedRowHeight = 70
        table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrOfDesText.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Cell
        cell.descLabel!.text = arrOfDesText[indexPath.row]
        cell.picImage!.image = UIImage(named: arrOfPictures[indexPath.row]!)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

Here is how it's looks like:
[image: my image]

So as you can see second cell don't show image but the height of that cell is still same like others and that is what i would like to change.

Answer (score 1):

You can set height for cell in `heightForRowAt indexPath` delegate method. Check the condition, in array at specific index path is not empty return automaticDimension otherwise estimated rows height

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

                let pic = arrOfPictures[indexPath.row]
                    if !pic.isEmpty {
                        return UITableView.automaticDimension  
                    }else{

                        return 70
                    }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved

Here is code and image:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var picImage : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var descLabel : UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

descLabel.numberOfLines = 0
contentView.addSubview(descLabel)
descLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
descLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
descLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true
descLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -35).isActive = true

contentView.addSubview(picImage)
picImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
picImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
picImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
picImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
picImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descLabel.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true


}


}
```

And controller class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let loading = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
var arrOfPictures : [String?] = ["str", "", "str"]
var arrOfDesText : [String] = ["sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text", "sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text", "sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text", "sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text", "sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text sometext sometext sometext some text"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.estimatedRowHeight = 70
    table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrOfDesText.count
}
var index = 0
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Cell
    cell.descLabel!.text = arrOfDesText[indexPath.row]
    if index < arrOfPictures.count {
        index += 1
        cell.picImage.image = UIImage(named: (arrOfPictures[indexPath.row]!))
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
}
```